# Different pylint outputs running in different directories

Tags: python, django, pylint

I'm trying to use pylint to check my web application code which uses Django. I know Pylint is a static checker, it has problem with attributes defined at runtime and Django uses those. However, I'd expect Pylint to always show the same errors, despite if I'm in Python code root directory or its parent directory. Sample:

```
code_repository_root
 |
 -- app_name
     |
      -- test_form.py
      -- test.py
```

test_form.py:

```
from django.forms import Form

class TestForm(Form):

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

test.py:

```
from appname.test_form import TestForm

def test():

    myform = TestForm()
    return myform.is_valid()
```

if I run pylint in the appname dir (pylint -E test.py), I get no errors. If I run pylint in the appname dir's parent dir (code repository root dir) (pylint -E appname/test.py), I get:

```
E:  6:test: Instance of 'TestForm' has no 'is_valid' member
```

I do not understand what is happening.

Comment: this may be a PYTHONPATH problem. Do you have properly an __init__.py file in your <appname> directory? Do you have some PYTHONPATH set? Does it work when you run python test.py and python <appname>/test.py?

Comment: Yes, __init__py is in <appname>. I am using default Python path. When test.py is inside <appname> dir, running 'python test.py' or 'python <appname>/test.py' do *not* work as I would expect. If I move test.py to code repository root, it works (because current dir is added automatically to python path). As Pylint does not require your app to be installed (therefore, in python path), I'd expect that this would not be an issue. And it is not an issue for most code, except some django attributes.